# Emoji only display on Chrome if I use "cursive" or "fantasy" font family

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, unicode, emoji

I'm having a perplexing issue with displaying emoji in Google Chrome. Emoji seem to render fine, but there is one case where no emoji render at all.

[image: image is on the DOM]

The image is on the DOM and in the HTML. The emoji renders in Chrome if I view the page source or open in the web inspector.

When I change the font-family of the div that contains the emoji, only `font-family: cursive` or `font-family: fantasy` actually make the emoji render.

[image: after applying font-family: cursive]

How can I get emoji to render without having to apply these fonts, and without relying on a 3rd party library? What could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emoji only seem to work with `font-weight: normal`. Applying this style to the div containing my emoji solved the problem.